# How to Activating Vscroll xplistbar Advance GUI PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Good morning everyone, I am using advance gui, can someone tell me how to activate Vscroll xplistbar, I checked Vscroll but still don't want to scroll, because using xp default up down is too slow, thank you for the help

Comment: Don't really understand your question.  You are talking about a vertical scrollbar control you don't want to scroll with?

Comment: Good morning, I am very happy that you Mr Matt Balent answered my question, I am following your tutorial entitled 100Days PowerBuilder. my question above is this, in pb12, there is an example called Advance GUI sample, there is an example of the Xplistbar sheet as the main menu, and in the Xplistbar properties there are scroll options, Hsrcoll and Vscroll, well, I want to use this Vscroll feature to scroll the xplistbar this, but even though I checked Vscroll, the xplistbar still won't scroll, sorry if my English is not good, I'm from Jakarta and not good at English. my respect, Herman